# Bishkek (or Almaty) to Novosibirsk next week

Tags: russia, trains, kyrgyzstan, bishkek, novosibirsk

Next week I'll be leaving Bishkek - a little short on time, and need to hot-foot it to Novosibirsk, Siberia.  Probably on Monday night or Tuesday day, depending on schedules.  Is there a direct train, or will I need to change - any online timetables for those countries?  I have visas for Kyrgyzstan, Kazakhstan and Russia all organised and in my passport already.

Comment: Russia! My favorite tag! :)

Comment: Thought it'd get your attention ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [direct train #385Щ(sch)](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=880a2e54) - this will be rail car leading right to the Novosibirsk (you should note that [tutu.ru](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/) is best site for russian trains, if you can read the Cyrillic), but you should be aware **it can be canceled**.

I suggest you to move to the Almaty, with such [trains available](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/rasp_d.php?nnst1=2700000&nnst2=2044000), with #385Щ still available:

- [Additional rail car #326Н(N)](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=6fbbb134), train from Almaty to Chita
- [Direct train #302Ц(tze)](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=6fbbb134)
- [Passing train #369Ф(F)](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=23a68725) from Tashkent to Novosibirsk

Comment: I can read some Cyrillic very slowly, so will go have a look ;)

Comment: @Mark Mayo Unfortunately this site does not have English version yet.

Comment: That's ok, I can read place names and times.  Definitely is looking like if I cross the border first thing and get to Almaty, I can get an afternoon train north.

Comment: For those who cannot read cyrillic, Google translation is worth a try. I successfully used it from turkish to english on Istanbul city bus timetables.

Comment: Yes, I think by this train it will the best case (if it will not be cancelled).

Answer (score 1):

Also try to post this @ http://mavtobus.ru/bishkek_kg/novosibirsk/ may be some drivers could help you there.